# Função Agregar no R

Tags: r

Boa tarde. Estou utilizando a função `aggregate` para agrupar alguns dados. Porém, estou utilizando apenas uma variável para somar. Gostaria de utilizar mais de uma variável. Isso é possível? Estou utilizando o seguinte exemplo:

```
TESTE = aggregate(VALOR ~ REFERENCIA + GRUPO_COPA + CIDADE, data=DADOS,FUN=sum)
```

Gostaria de utilizar variável `QTDE` junto a `VALOR` para somar, ou seja, acrescentar mais uma coluna, ficando as seguintes colunas:
`REFERENCIA`, `GRUPO_COPA`, `CIDADE`, `VALOR`, `QTDE`
É possível no `aggregate` ou em outra função este exemplo? Grato

Vejam aí meu exemplo utilizando o `dput(DADOS)`:

```
structure(list(REFERENCIA = c("JAN_2017", "JAN_2017", "JAN_2017", "JAN_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017" ), GRUPO_COPA = c("AZUL", "AZUL", "AMARELO", "AMARELO", "VERDE", "VERDE", "VERDE", "AZUL", "AZUL"), CIDADE = c("SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "RJ", "BSB", "BSB", "BSB", "SP"), VALOR = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000), QTDE = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17)), .Names = c("REFERENCIA", "GRUPO_COPA", "CIDADE", "VALOR", "QTDE"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```